# Haproxy redirection but keeping the URL same?

Tags: haproxy, haproxy-ingress

I have a xml file under https://example.com/assets/content/foo.xml but I want it to access it as https://example.com/foo.xml. So outcome will be, the browser URL SHOULD BE = https://example.com/foo.xml  but I will get the  file context from https://example.com/assets/content/foo.xml location. How to set it in haproxy ?

I tried many solutions but none of them worked. here is what I tried and this would be completely wrong.

```
acl SEO_XML  path_beg -i /foo.xml
http-request set-header         X-Location-Path %[capture.req.uri] if SEO_XML
http-request replace-header     X-Location-Path /foo.xml /assets/content/foo.xml if SEO_XML
http-request redirect location  %[hdr(X-Location-Path)] if SEO_XML
use_backend shiba_dev_https            if SEO_XML
```

I have also tried other solutions as follows :

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /foo.xml/(.*)    \1\ /assets/content/foo.xml/\2
```

```
  http-request set-header Host example.com
  http-request replace-path /foo.xml(.*) /assets/content/foo.xml\1
```

None of this worked as I have no clue how to do it. Any ideas pls ?

Haproxy Version = 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reqirep  ^([^\ :]*)\ /foo.xml\ (.*) \1\ /assets/content/foo.xml\ \2 if { path_beg /foo.xml }
```